# Emulator does not working in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

[This is my problem look like and i can't understand what the error occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJT4A.png)

Comment: The details you provided are not enough to understand the situation. Did you start the emulator via internal adm integration or externally? If you did it externally have you tried opening adb to connect the device?

Comment: i started the emulator from avd manager in android studio

Comment: That's strange, in that case you should have a `run` tab in your console. Try to close everything and start from scratch